# My Trigger getting looping and Case Error when i try to join two tables on it

Tags: oracle

I have 2 tables, Contract and Bankslip.

I need to get the date field from the Contract table, and set the date on Bankslip table, but it's getting in a loop, I think!

How can i do it?

Here is my code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER GFLANCAM_ATUALIZA_DATA_EMISSAO
    BEFORE INSERT ON GFLANCAM
    FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

    DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO DATE;

BEGIN

    CASE WHEN :NEW.DOCUMENTO <> ' ' then  

        SELECT dt_inicio 
           INTO DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO 
        from ctcontra 
        where cd_contrato = :NEW.documento;

    :NEW.data := DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO;

    END CASE;

END;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: When its not on looping, its throw the error: CASE not found while executing CASE statment

Comment: That error means that you haven't got a default clause at the end of your `CASE` statement. Perhaps you should switch over to an `IF` statement instead, as that's less restrictive (the default for an `IF` statement, if you don't add an `ELSE` clause, is to do nothing). And what do you mean by "when it's not on looping"?

Comment: About looping, in some cases, its not throw the error, instead of it, the system freeze, and i suppose its on looping because of the trigger....but, i will try using IF, to see what happens, and i will came back, to say if it work. Ty!

Comment: There's no looping in your trigger, so if things are "freezing", it's most likely not related to your trigger; it could be a lock or some other part of your code that's causing the issue.

Comment: Hey Boneist, with IF, its not getting the error anymore, but it keep's freezing, and i think i know what is going on: when i create the SubContract, the Code of the contract (cd_contrato) is not created yet! I think i need to do it "after" insert, and not before....my fear is if the trigger will run through all the DB!

Answer (score 1):

Much of the trigger is unnecessary.

You can accomplish your goal without the `CASE` and without defining a variable.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GFLANCAM_ATUALIZA_DATA_EMISSAO
   BEFORE INSERT
   ON GFLANCAM
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   -- Consider following:
   -- IF NVL (:NEW.DOCUMENTO, ' ') <> ' '
   IF :NEW.DOCUMENTO <> ' '
   THEN
      -- Following line may cause ORA-01403: no data found
      SELECT dt_inicio INTO :NEW.data FROM ctcontra WHERE cd_contrato = :NEW.documento;
   END IF;
END;
/
```

A few notes:

If you want to catch `NULL` values then add the `NVL` shown above.

Watch out for the case where a corresponding record is not found in `ctcontra`--this condition would result in `ORA-01403: no data found` (which might be exactly what you want in this case).

Make sure that `ctcontra` has only one record for each `cd_contrato` value, otherwise you will get a `ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the update:

```
{CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER GFLANCAM_ATUALIZA_DATA_EMISSAO
AFTER INSERT ON GFLANCAM
FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO DATE;

BEGIN

IF DOCUMENTO <> ' ' THEN  
    SELECT dt_inicio INTO DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO from ctcontra where cd_contrato = 
DOCUMENTO;  
    UPDATE GFLANCAM SET DATA = DATA_INICIO_CONTRATO;
END IF;

END;}
```

Comment: It will run through all the database?

Comment: This will not work. It will cause a `ORA-04091: table GFLANCAM is mutating` error. You can't perform an `UPDATE` on the same table in a row-level trigger like this.

Comment: How can i do it, on "after insert", any idea?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? You can't change the row in an `AFTER` trigger, so you should use a `BEFORE` trigger. This word only means that the trigger executes before the changes are actually written to the database--it's the moment when your code can postprocess the record. See if the code I provided in my answer works.